# Prove that a "prime graph" is Bipartite.

Tags: graph-theory

Let the prime graph be defined as the graph of all natural numbers, with two vertices being connected if the sum of the numbers on the two vertices add up to a prime number. Prove that the prime graph is Bipartite.

Comment: What work have you done on it so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The natural numbers must not include $0$.  Consider odd and even numbers.